# Wine missing libncurses.5.4.dylib

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, homebrew, wine

When I launch winecfg or some other executables, I get this terminal output-

> Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.5.4.dylib).

It does not prevent programs from running, but it's just annoying.
How can I fix that?

Background detail:

- I installed wine via homebrew, after running `brew doctor` (to make
  sure my homebrew env is set up alright).
- I use a MacBook Pro late 2013 Retina Haswell (MacBookPro11,3)